# How to use lookup table to produce readable output

Tags: mysql

I have this query which works fine:

```
SELECT PLAY_ID, A0, WORD, CONTEXT

FROM playdata

WHERE A0 LIKE 'SOMETHING'
```

This produces somewhat useful output. But there is a column called PLAY_ID and that is just a number. There is a table called plays and that table you can look up the PLAY_ID and find out the TITLE and the YEAR.

So I want to output three things, the first two from the lookup table, the CONTEXT and WORD from the original playdata:

```
TITLE | YEAR | WORD | CONTEXT
```

Comment: You should research JOIN

Comment: You need an INNER JOIN. You can find examples easily online

Comment: this is a basic sql question try a search for a simple tutorial online  and take a look at join

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TITLE, CREATION_YEAR, A0, WORD, CONTEXT
FROM playdata
INNER JOIN plays
ON playdata.PLAY_ID=plays.PLAY_ID
WHERE A0 LIKE 'SOMETHING'
```